# extracting UUID from response in jmeter

Tags: perl, jmeter

i am using Jmeter to simulate multiple users to upload a file into server
i used Badboy to record a script and export it to Jmeter
to upload a file a need to get the UUID that is responded by the server so i can use it for the rest of the HTTP request i have tried to use regular expression extractor using this expression
`${UUID} = \S*`

but it did not work also i used the uuid function to generate a random UUID but i could not configure it in a way to make the request repeated until match the UUID the have been returned by the server
any one can help me?

Comment: is that Perl? because it doesn't look Perl. please post some more context to the code in question.

Comment: when i looked to the jmeter user guide it says that the regular expression need to be written in Perl-type regular expression so i searched about it and this is whata i have got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For extracting UUID you'll need to configure [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) Post Processor as follows:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. **UUID**
- Regular Expression: for Version 4 UUID it would be something like **([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[89aAbB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12})**
- Template: **$1$**

You can test your regular expression against returned data using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener (select RegExp Tester from dropdown)

For more information refer to [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) guide.